# Excel vba macro unavailable in a sheet exported using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, vba

So, I have an xlsx file that is generated using pandas ExcelWriter.The exact piece of code being

```
writer=pd.ExcelWriter(r'Workbook.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') 
writer.save()
```

Parallely I have an excel macro that is generated to be available for all excel workbooks. The macros are available when I open excel and create an empty workbook. When I open the workbook exported using pandas, the excel macros are not even listed.

This is the file I created manually

[image: Manually created excel file]

This is the file generated using the python code

[image: Excel file exported from pandas]

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That would suggest your PERSONAL.xlsb file is not open.

Comment: @BigBen, wow that worked. I didnt know that. But now I have a new problem. The macro for some reason doesnt even work. Any tips?

Comment: You may need to specify how it "doesn't work", including sample code and any error messages, if applicable.